# How to import Swift Pods to Swift Project without Objective-C Bridging header file

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

How to import Swift Pods to Swift Project without Objective-C Bridging header file?
I install cocoapods to my project with Alamofire framework.
I make import Alamofire and this works.

But when I install ImageLoader pod and when I try import ImageLoader, Xcode show me error "Cannot load underlying module for 'ImageLoader'".

When I try initialise class ImageLoader, Xcode also show error "Use of unresolved identifier"

My Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire',        '~> 1.2'
pod 'ObjectMapper',     '~> 0.9'
pod 'ImageLoader',      '~> 0.3.0'
pod 'Locksmith'
```

Comment: Can you post your `Podfile`?

Comment: @KeithSmiley, a add Podfile to content.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  when i install ImageLoader via cocoapods and import ImageLoader it loads it fine.  Is it a case where you need to delete your pods folder and .lock file and pod install again?